# Align composable to bottom of another composable in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I have 3 composable in Column and I want to align 2nd composable to bottom of 1st composable like this:

[image]

But currently i'm getting output like this:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposePlaygroundTheme {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()) {
                    topControls("Game 1",34,Modifier.weight(1f))
                    centerControls()
                    bottomControls()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun topControls(gamename: String, totalTime: Int, modifier: Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier
        .background(Color.LightGray)
        .padding(start = 24.dp, end = 24.dp, top = 24.dp)) {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 32.dp)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground),
                contentDescription = "",
                Modifier
                    .height(32.dp)
                    .width(32.dp)
            )
            Text(
                text = gamename,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }
        Text(text = totalTime.toString(),modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), textAlign = TextAlign.Center,fontSize = 53.sp)
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
            contentDescription = "",
            Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun centerControls() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()) {
        Divider(color = Color.Blue, thickness = 1.dp, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
        Row(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp)) {
            Button(onClick = {  },colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = Color.Black,contentColor = Color.White), modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(end = 20.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()) {
                Text(text = "End Game",modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight(), textAlign = TextAlign.Center,fontSize = 20.sp)
            }
            Image(painter = ColorPainter(Color.Gray), contentDescription = "", modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 25.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
                .height(32.dp)
                .width(32.dp))
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun bottomControls() {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(170.dp))
}
```

Is there anyway I can achieve this in jetpack compose without using Constraint layout?

Comment: I'm pretty new to Compose, but why not to use ConstraintLayout, when the layout gets complex like this one?

Answer (score 4):

As you need to place one view under an other one, you should use `Box`.

Using `Modifier.align`, you can specify position of your `centerControls`, in this case `Alignment.BottomCenter`.

Using `Modifier.layout` you can add offset, equal to half view size.

```kotlin
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .fillMaxSize()
) {
    Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        topControls("Game 1", 34, Modifier.fillMaxHeight())
        centerControls(
            Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                    val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                    layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                        placeable.place(0, placeable.height / 2)
                    }
                }
        )
    }
    bottomControls()
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
  ComposePlaygroundTheme {
                Column(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()) {
                    topControls("Game 1",34)
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) { // FrameLayout, weight will occupy rest of the content
                          centerControls()
                          bottomControls() // will be stacked up on top of topControls()
                     }
                    
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but this will not provide required output. this code will just draw bottomControls() on top of centerControls() that's not what i need. i want to align center of centerControls() to bottom of topControls() like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6EP6.png. as you can see in image divider of centerControls() is align with bottom of topControls()